# How to align text (alone) of a QToolButton

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a **QToolButton**. I'm using it instead of **QPushButton** because I need a label-like looking button. **QPushButton** is too chunky even after setting stylesheet's borders and paddings to `None-0px`.

I would like this **QToolButton** to contain a text (no-icon) align right.

However, `text-align: right;` is not working. `.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)` is also not working.

How can I align the text to right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to sub-class QStyle and re-implement QStyle::drawControl() to align the text to the right. Check the file qt/src/gui/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp to see how it's done. (Sorry I'm using C++ not Python)

```
case CE_ToolButtonLabel:
    if (const QStyleOptionToolButton *toolbutton
            = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionToolButton *>(opt)) {
        QRect rect = toolbutton->rect;
        int shiftX = 0;
        int shiftY = 0;
        if (toolbutton->state & (State_Sunken | State_On)) {
            shiftX = proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftHorizontal, toolbutton, widget);
            shiftY = proxy()->pixelMetric(PM_ButtonShiftVertical, toolbutton, widget);
        }
        // Arrow type always overrules and is always shown
        bool hasArrow = toolbutton->features & QStyleOptionToolButton::Arrow;
        if (((!hasArrow && toolbutton->icon.isNull()) && !toolbutton->text.isEmpty())
            || toolbutton->toolButtonStyle == Qt::ToolButtonTextOnly) {
            int alignment = Qt::AlignCenter | Qt::TextShowMnemonic;
```

Comment: This is excellent, what a great idea! Translating from C++ to Python shouldn't be an issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This example of align button content (icon & text) to center, but you can adopt this example to your demands (align to right). Override QToolButoon::paintEvent as next:

```
void CMyToolButton::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* )
{
  QStylePainter sp( this );
  QStyleOptionToolButton opt;
  initStyleOption( &opt );
  const QString strText = opt.text;
  const QIcon icn = opt.icon;
  //draw background
  opt.text.clear();
  opt.icon = QIcon();
  sp.drawComplexControl( QStyle::CC_ToolButton, opt );
  //draw content
  const int nSizeHintWidth = minimumSizeHint().width();
  const int nDiff = qMax( 0, ( opt.rect.width() - nSizeHintWidth ) / 2 );
  opt.text = strText;
  opt.icon = icn;
  opt.rect.setWidth( nSizeHintWidth );//reduce paint area to minimum
  opt.rect.translate( nDiff, 0 );//offset paint area to center
  sp.drawComplexControl( QStyle::CC_ToolButton, opt );
}
```